# how to make ui screens in android auto adjustable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have designed few screens in which I have given layout width and height as wrap content and used dp and sp only but still the ui varies from one mobile to other.Please let me know where I am going wrong.

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="1dp"
    tools:context=".view.FragmentViews.RMDashboardActitvity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Available"
                android:textColor="#82BCB4"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/theSwitchId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:switchMinWidth="95dp"
                android:track="@drawable/switch_bg"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:thumbTint="#224e6d"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="UnAvailable"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:textColor="#224e6d"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="37dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/maincv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#224e6d">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/person_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/person_photo"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_customer" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/person_photo"
                        android:text="CUSTOMER"
                        android:textColor="#bae2db"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundededittext"
                    android:hint="     Search"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/person_details"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

                <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/searchView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dashboard_border"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/registercustomerrl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/plus"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_register_customer" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/plus"
                    android:text="REGISTER CUSTOMER"
                    android:textColor="#224e6d"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plus" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: you can try new feature of Android **PercentRelativeLayout**. Here is the reference link of it : http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/

Comment: you can use  weightsum

Comment: all the values you are giving to layouts must be placed in dimens.xml file. based on the device specs there will be multiple dimens.xml files. It will help adjusting the view in multiple devices

Answer (score 1):

For that please use below methodology

- Try to use drawables like drawable-hdpi , drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi which images you want to use in your app.
- Try to use **dp** in fix size instead of **px**
- Try to avoid to give fix or absolute size in app
- Try to use dimens.xml like res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml , res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml for give margins , padding etc.
- Try to use weight or layout weight to divide.

If you need more help I would appreciate if you can ask.

Comment: i have used dp only and i didnt understand the last point that u have told @Vatsal Shah

Comment: If you are adding layout and want to screen divide in some parts use layout:weight or weight or weighsum so it will divide screens with auto adjustment.